# How Do I move my mouse with flexible speed

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pywin32

I read something about pywin32 with give's you the possibility to move the curser to One Point to another.

How would I Click on one point and move it with a specific speed to another direction without the cursor "jumping" to that direction?
I want a result where you could see what points it has passed.

OS is Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have two points, a start and a stop; you can calculate the line equation between them and just call `win32api.SetCursorPos` multiple times to animate the movement.

```
import win32api, time

def moveFromTo(p1, p2):
    # slope of our line
    m = (p2[1] - p1[1]) / (p2[0] - p1[0])
    # y intercept of our line
    i = p1[1] - m * p1[0]
    # current point
    cP = p1
    # while loop comparison
    comp = isGreater
    # moving left to right or right to left
    inc = -1
    # switch for moving to right
    if (p2[0] > p1[0]):
        comp = isLess
        inc = 1
    # move cursor one pixel at a time
    while comp(cP[0],p2[0]):
        win32api.SetCursorPos(cP)
        cP[0] += inc
        # get next point on line
        cP[1] = m * cP[0] + i
        # slow it down
        time.sleep(0.01)

def isLess(a,b):
    return a < b
def isGreater(a,b):
    return a > b

moveFromTo([500,500],[100,100])
```